# spring-jpa-1.0.xsd conflict

Tags: java, spring

I'm a Spring newbie and I'm having trouble with my namespace and it apparently involves the spring-jpa-1.0.xsd. I've noticed that other people have also had this. The problem is that spring-jpa-1.0.xsd hardcoded the version of spring-context to 3.0., but I haven't seen a clear explanation on how to fix it.  My xml begins as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
```

The error I get is:

```
 The errors below were detected when validating the file "spring-jpa-1.0.xsd" via the file "datasource-tx-jpa.xml".
```

My POM for jpa is:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I changed the version to

```
  <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

But now I'm getting a missing artifact error that I don't know how to fix.

Anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating to `spring-jpa-1.1`

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.1.xsd"
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
```

**pom.xml**

```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, that got rid of one problem, but now "Build path is incomplete" errors.

Comment: Make sure you include your maven libraries in the deployment assembly.